# Apple wireless keyboard it's always turned off at startup

Tags: keyboard, mac, bluetooth

My wireless Apple bluetooth keyboard has been acting up recently. While I use the computer it works just fine but every time I boot up the computer after it has been shut down the keyboard, which is always left on, is turned off and I need to power it up - every time the computer starts up.

On the other hand my magic mouse works wonderfully, so I understand this isn't normal behavior.

How can I get the keyboard to stay on despite computer power cycles?

Answer (score 1):

So the keyboard really needs to long-press turn on again? That's weird.

But these are things I will try:

Re-Pair the keyboard. Delete it from the known bluetooth device list, and pair it again.

Test the keyboard with other Macs

Replace the battery